# when starting jenkins it is starting but when checking status of jenkins it is saying active(exited)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jenkins, centos

I had changed the permissions of /home/centos to sudo chmod -R 777 /home on which jenkins is hosted after that i'm not able to login to the machine then i had created one more instance and detached the jenkins disk attached to new machine changed the permissions then attached the disk to the jenkins machine. From then i'm able to login but when starting the jenkins it is saying active(exited).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is regarding with the permission' i tried to run 'jenkinsuser=root' it worked fine.